# Use both owasp CRS and Comodo modsecurity rule set simultaneously

Tags: mod-security, web-application-firewall

In a modsecurity installation could I setup and use both owasp CRS (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/) and Comodo rule set (https://waf.comodo.com/user/cwaf_revisions) simultaneously?

Are they incompatible?

Is it wrong, pointless and or unnecessary?